# Create nested JSON in a Zapier Code step to pass through to Formstack Documents

Tags: python, data-structures, zapier, formstack

Trigger: Pipedrive deal moved to stage
Output: Merged Formstack Document with product line items from deal

Using the [tablerow](https://support.webmerge.me/hc/en-us/articles/206526116-Loop-through-a-list-of-items) function available in Formstack Documents we're able to populate a table with a new line created for each item in a list. Currently the only way to do this is using a Formstack Documents run script, setting up the webhook in Pipedrive to hit a URL that they host. When a lot of requests are slowing down their script server(s) there can be a huge delay in document merging so we're trying to recreate the functionality provided by the script in a Zap.

Zapier separates out each of the values so they're grouped by key name:

[image: line items as input in zapier]

Using a Python code step I'd like to combine some of these (name, code, unit, quantity and category) so that it can be parsed through to Formstack Documents which can then use its tablerow function to loop through the products.

I'm open to formatting the data and passing it through to Formstack Documents via their REST API in the same code step if needed.

My thinking is:

Pass each of the items I want to use through to a code step as separate inputs
Combine each line item so that it becomes a nested (array/dictionary/json?)
Pass this output through to Formstack Documents.